# Determine which interfaces a class explicitly implements, excluding inheritance

Tags: php

I'm working on a GUI which introspects its working environment to provide a visual representation of class hierarchy.

I need to get the list of interfaces that a class explicitly implements, excluding the inherited ones, much like `class_uses()`. Both `class_implements()` and `ReflectionClass::getInterfaceNames()` seem to return all interfaces implemented in the hierarchy.

Example:

```php
interface A {}
interface B {}
interface C {}
interface D extends C {}
class M implements A,B {}
class N extends M implements B,D {}

// For N I need some getOwnInterfaces('N') function to return ['B','D']
// class_implements('N') returns ['A','B','C','D']
```

Note in the example above, `interface B` is declared as implemented both at the super class and on the specialized class. I actually have practical occurences of this in the code.

Comment: Why redeclare `N` as implementing `B` if `M` already implements it? I assume this was done for the simplicity of the example, but it doesn't hurt to check.

Comment: @El_Vanja I added that case on purpose to show that just implementing a `disjunction(class_implements($class), class_implements(get_parent_class($class)))` will not quite do the trick, it would be close enough but not quite what I'm looking for. I've seen the duplicate implements occur in practice, maybe due to sloppy code maintenance, but that's not the issue to address here. I've edited the example to make my intention more clear.

Comment: With all the additional development in this post... I'd say outside of directly parsing the contents of the file, I don't see how this would be done. I hope someone with more knowledge can either confirm or dispute this, since I'm now interested if this is possible.

Comment: Well, parsing a big codebase with i.e. https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser is excruciatingly slow so I too hope there is a more straightforward way to get to it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of implemented interfaces, then for each one check if it is also implemented by the base class (several methods available to do that).

Interfaces that are *not* implemented by the base class are those implemented directly.

Comment: Although that is the most logical way, the OP has a requirement to allow re-declaring of interfaces on child classes, too. That is the `B` example in their post.

Comment: Well, yes and no, please see the case of `interface B` above and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65995036/determine-which-interfaces-a-class-explicitly-implements-excluding-inheritance/65995381#comment116682998_65995036

While this is close enough to what I need, it's not exactly what I need. I have practical instances where the class hierarchy declares implementing the same interface multiple times (presumably due to code consolidation resulting in interface merges)

Comment: @Dinu I don't understand your requirement. The hierarchy cannot just *declare* that they implement the interface (unless the class is abstract), it must also *implement* it. So the interface can end up being implemented more than once, but in that case what makes one implementation "better" than another?

Comment: @Dinu it also seems that a trivial modification to the idea would cover that anyway? Get the set of interfaces implemented directly as above, and then get the list of interfaces implemented by the base class (not only directly, you don't need to filter them here). Then the difference of these sets is the interfaces implemented by your leaf class only.

Comment: Well, this usually happens in 2 situations; say at some point in time there are 2 implementations `class A implements I {...}` and `class B implements I {...}`; at some point, someone notices that `A` and `B` duplicate 70% of the code and decides, 'hey, let's consolidate the code'. And the code will change to `class A extends ABAbstract implements I {...}` and `class B extends ABAbstract implements I {...}`. Sometimes people forget to move the `implements I` on the abstract AND remove the `implements` on the specialisations.

Comment: The other situation is when there were historically two interfaces `I1` and `I2` implemented at different levels of the hierarchy, then at some point someone decided he doesn't need the specialisation so everyone now implements `I12`, except, again, nobody cares to purge the tree of the redundant implements. Either way, it's not an option, it's a matter of fact, big code that I need to represent visually as it is.

Comment: I don't see how this trivial modification you suggest is supposed to work. _"Get the set of interfaces implemented directly as above"_ - gets `C`; _"and then get the list of interfaces implemented by the base class"_ - gets `A, B`. The difference of those sets is either of the sets, depending on which one you set as the first. In both cases, not the desired result.

Comment: And this just pointed out another problem to me: `class A implements I {}; interface I extends I2, I3{}` leaves me with `I2` and `I3` in `class_implements()`. I don't want that either. Edited the example to also reflect this.

Comment: It is supposed to work like this: https://ideone.com/SA9mcr

Comment: However, let me be very frank here. I don't know what you are trying to accomplish exactly, and hence all of this might be wrong, _but_: I am quite an experienced dev, and this whole discussion _screams_ to me that you are trying to do something that you shouldn't, because you are set on treating concepts like "what does it mean to implement an interface" in a way that does not match the formal logic of the programming language in question. It might be worth it to take a step (or several) back and consider if you have the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/) here.

Comment: @Jon, you are partially right; what I need to do, in the simplest terms I can formulate it, is "I need to graphically represent the written code, the way it is written". So yes, it's in the domain of meta-programming, which is not the first design concern for a language. Nevertheless, I still need to do it.

Comment: I have considered using an AST parser like https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser but in my previous experience with it, it's too slow for on-demand parsing of a full codebase, but with the right caching, it might be an option... I was hoping for a better one, if there was a built-in no-dev way that would've been excellent, so I figured I might ask. I mean, PHP's reflection mechanism provides everything I need except this glitch with interfaces.

Comment: After thorough research, what you suggested appears to be the best that can be achieved, so I will accept this answer... you could add the code snippet in comments to the answer, for better visibility